# min value of multi column primary key

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

i have three tables like this

`sales_bill` with columns (`id`, `time`, `user_id`, `branch_id`)

`sales` with columns (`id`, `bill_id`, `quantity`, `item_id`)

`sales_plus` with columns (`sales_id`, `status`, `time`, `branch_id`, `user_id`)

where sales_plus.status is enum('add', 'remove') and one item can be added or removed after the original bill is done and this table primary key is sales_id and status

i need to select the sales with specific bill_id but if the item was added and removed from the bill it shows only removed with its time, branch_id and user_id

here is the best i could do but due to usage of ANY_VALUE it can return the time of the add but with the removed status

```
SELECT
bill.id as bill_id,
bill.user_id as bill_user_id,
bill.branch_id as bill_branch_id,
bill.time as bill_time,
sales.id as sales_id,
item_id,
quantity,
price,
min(status) AS status,
ANY_VALUE(sales_plus.user_id) AS sales_plus_user_id,
ANY_VALUE(sales_.branch_id) AS sales_plus_branch_id,
ANY_VALUE(sales_.time) AS sales_plus_time,
FROM sales
INNER JOIN sales_bill
ON sales.bill_id = bill.id
LEFT JOIN sales_plus
ON sales.id = sales_plus.sales_id
WHERE bill_id = :bill_id
GROUP BY sales.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what is your goal, but it looks like you are searching for sales, with "minimum" status only. If so, this query should do the job:

```
select * 
  from 
   sales_bill, sales, sales_plus 
  where 
    bill_id = 0 and 
    sales_bill.id = sales.bill_id and 
    sales.id = sales_plus.sales_id and 
    sales_plus.status = (
       select sp.status from sales_plus as sp where sp.sales_id = sales.id order by status limit 1
    );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37b488/2/0

Comment: my goal is that i don't want to duplicate the rows for the same sale so if it was added and removed then i just need to see the removed time, branch and user